# Ubuntu 16.04 - Apply ESM security patches only using unattended-upgrade

Tags: esm

We have purchased ESM for a number Ubuntu 16.04  servers, installed Ubuntu Advantage Tools and enabled UA. How can I install only security patches including ESM using unattended-upgrade command? We don't want to run 'apt-get upgrade'

Comment: It's a question for ESM support. Here is off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

The setting for `Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins` affects what repositories are used by `unattended-upgrade`.  These are defined by default in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`.

You could add a separate configuration file (e.g. `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90custom`) with the content

```
#clear Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins;
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-updates";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-security";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";
        "${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-apps-security";
};
```

These entries match all ESM repo formats for all distros that I have worked with, but you can tailor for your needs.

I like to use a separate configuration file to avoid conflicts with system packages that update the default configuration file.